# translate Ruby regex to php/perl regex

Tags: php, ruby, regex, preg-match-all

I have made this regex, which works fine in Ruby:

```
/(1?[[\(\s\.-]]\d{3}\)?[\s\.-]\d{3}[\s\.-]\d{4}(\z[^\d])?)/
```

It's for extracting phone numbers from text document but now I'm using the same expression in PHP, using `preg_match_all`. Now the same expression gives me an empty array.
I don't understand why this is happening

What do I need to change about this expression to make it work in PHP?

Comment: Please add some sample input numbers to the question also.

Comment: I agree with @Casper. You need to supply test data and show examples of expected results when asking a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a strange error in your Regexp. I think it's partially luck it's working on Rubular:

```
(1?[[\(\s\.-]]\d{3}\)?[\s\.-]\d{3}[\s\.-]\d{4}(\z[^\d])?)
   ^         ^
```

Why are those brackets there two times?

See here for a working version where I just removed those. Works fine with PHP now:

http://www.regex101.com/r/gR6kS3/1

```
(1?[\(\s\.-]\d{3}\)?[\s\.-]\d{3}[\s\.-]\d{4}(\z[^\d])?)
```

Comment: you really have a eye of bird that was awesome.This is working absolutely fine.

Comment: actually not only at rubular that was going well in ruby too.so that was the reason i was not able to see that brackets :P Thanks alot for this.

Comment: @vivekporwal04 Yep. You sometimes get blinded by your own code. It happens to everyone :)